# Getting a random function from a list of functions and calling the selected function

Tags: python, list, function, random

I'm trying to create a function that I can call and it selects a random function from a list of functions and calls the selected function into action. Is that even possible? Here what I have tried. Which results in nothing happening.

```
import random

def ran1(): 
    print("test1")

def ran2(): 
    print("test2") 

def ran3(): 
    print("test3") 

def ran4(): 
    print("test4")

list_functions = [ran1,ran2,ran3,ran4]

def ran_choice():
    random.choice(list_functions)

ran_choice()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is fine. You just need to call the function you choose in `ran_choice`:

```
def ran_choice():
    random.choice(list_functions)()
```

Although, it might be easier to read as:

```
def ran_choice():
    chosen_fn = random.choice(list_functions)
    chosen_fn()
```